# I think R(X) ={1,2,3,4} but how to find $f_x(k)$

Tags: probability

$9$ tires from different brands are ranked from $1$ to $9$ (best to worst).

Let $X$ be the rank of the best tire among $6$ randomly chosen tires.

I think $R(X)$ = $\{1,2,3,4\}$ but how do you find $f_x(k)$?

Thank you.

Comment: how did you arrive at $R(X)=\{1,2,3,4\}$? Can you please explain?

Comment: @jay-sun i am not sure. I ask you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question it can be solved with simple enumeration.  All possible samplings, with equal probability:

```
(* Mathematica code *)
sets = Subsets[Range@9, {6}]
```

> ```
> {
> {{1,2,3,4,5,6},{1,2,3,4,5,7},{1,2,3,4,5,8},{1,2,3,4,5,9}},
> {{1,2,3,4,6,7},{1,2,3,4,6,8},{1,2,3,4,6,9},{1,2,3,4,7,8}},
> {{1,2,3,4,7,9},{1,2,3,4,8,9},{1,2,3,5,6,7},{1,2,3,5,6,8}},
> {{1,2,3,5,6,9},{1,2,3,5,7,8},{1,2,3,5,7,9},{1,2,3,5,8,9}},
> {{1,2,3,6,7,8},{1,2,3,6,7,9},{1,2,3,6,8,9},{1,2,3,7,8,9}},
> {{1,2,4,5,6,7},{1,2,4,5,6,8},{1,2,4,5,6,9},{1,2,4,5,7,8}},
> {{1,2,4,5,7,9},{1,2,4,5,8,9},{1,2,4,6,7,8},{1,2,4,6,7,9}},
> {{1,2,4,6,8,9},{1,2,4,7,8,9},{1,2,5,6,7,8},{1,2,5,6,7,9}},
> {{1,2,5,6,8,9},{1,2,5,7,8,9},{1,2,6,7,8,9},{1,3,4,5,6,7}},
> {{1,3,4,5,6,8},{1,3,4,5,6,9},{1,3,4,5,7,8},{1,3,4,5,7,9}},
> {{1,3,4,5,8,9},{1,3,4,6,7,8},{1,3,4,6,7,9},{1,3,4,6,8,9}},
> {{1,3,4,7,8,9},{1,3,5,6,7,8},{1,3,5,6,7,9},{1,3,5,6,8,9}},
> {{1,3,5,7,8,9},{1,3,6,7,8,9},{1,4,5,6,7,8},{1,4,5,6,7,9}},
> {{1,4,5,6,8,9},{1,4,5,7,8,9},{1,4,6,7,8,9},{1,5,6,7,8,9}},
> {{2,3,4,5,6,7},{2,3,4,5,6,8},{2,3,4,5,6,9},{2,3,4,5,7,8}},
> {{2,3,4,5,7,9},{2,3,4,5,8,9},{2,3,4,6,7,8},{2,3,4,6,7,9}},
> {{2,3,4,6,8,9},{2,3,4,7,8,9},{2,3,5,6,7,8},{2,3,5,6,7,9}},
> {{2,3,5,6,8,9},{2,3,5,7,8,9},{2,3,6,7,8,9},{2,4,5,6,7,8}},
> {{2,4,5,6,7,9},{2,4,5,6,8,9},{2,4,5,7,8,9},{2,4,6,7,8,9}},
> {{2,5,6,7,8,9},{3,4,5,6,7,8},{3,4,5,6,7,9},{3,4,5,6,8,9}},
> {{3,4,5,7,8,9},{3,4,6,7,8,9},{3,5,6,7,8,9},{4,5,6,7,8,9}},
> }
> ```

From there you can simply count the number of samplings in which the smallest number is 1, 2, 3, or 4.

```
Min /@ Subsets[Range@9, {6}] // Tally // Sort // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 56 \\
 2 & 21 \\
 3 & 6 \\
 4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$

Therefore the probabilities are just:

```
{56, 21, 6, 1} / 84`
```

> ```
> {0.666667, 0.25, 0.0714286, 0.0119048}
> ```

Comment: you could do this analytically....

Comment: @alexandreC yes, *you* could.  Don't let me keep you for posting an answer. :^)

Comment: very kind of you, but the author of the question only has an accepteance rate of 36%, so will give it  miss!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: +1 for your consideration to my question.